# Am i implementing pointers in a function correctly?

Tags: c, pointers

I am not understanding how to implement pointers in functions, it would be great if someone could help me out and tell me what I am doing wrong and how to modify it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sum(int *, int *, int *);

int main()
{
    int num1, num2, total;

    printf("Enter Two Numbers");
    scanf("\n%d%d", &num1, &num2);
    sum(&num1, &num2, &total);
    printf("\nThe Sum is %d", total);
}

void sum(int *a, int *b, int *c)
{
    *c = *a + *c;
}
```

Comment: Please explain why you think that you are doing anything wrong. What happens/does not happen in contrast to what you want?

Comment: It might be hard to understand, but even if somebody successfully guesses what your problem with the code is and you get an answer based on that guessing, even then an unclear question does not match the idea of StackOverflow. Please [edit] your question to explain what the problem actually is. "What is the problem with this code?" is not a good question. Here is more information for you: [tour], [ask] https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/ https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: I actually VTC'ed this for "simple typographical error", but oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Right here's your issue:

```
    *c = *a + *c;
```

You're adding `*a` and `*c`, not `*a` and `*b`.

Here's fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sum(int *, int *, int *);

int main()
{
    int num1, num2, total;

    printf("Enter Two Numbers");
    scanf("\n%d%d", &num1, &num2);
    sum(&num1, &num2, &total);
    printf("\nThe Sum is %d", total);
}

void sum(int *a, int *b, int *c)
{
    *c = *a + *b;
}
```

Other than that, good job!